# qplot size different geoms?

Tags: r, ggplot2, size

I am trying to plot both the points and the regression line in `qplot`. But I would like to just make the points bigger, not the line. For example, if I used the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
qplot(mpg,wt, data=mtcars, size=I(2), geom=c("point", "smooth"), method="lm")
```

Both the size for points and the lines are set to 2. But if I do:

```
qplot(mpg,wt, data=mtcars, size=c(I(3),I(1)), geom=c("point", "smooth"), method="lm")
```

R is not going to take it.

Is there a way to achieve this using `qplot`?

Comment: Please post a reproducible code, thank you.

Comment: I get `Error: Unknown parameters: method` with `ggplot2` version `2.0.0`.

Comment: It works on mine. My ggplot is 2.0.1

Comment: The `method` is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I meant, your code doesn't work with the last version of `ggplot2` available on CRAN. And there is no `ggplot2 2.0.1` at the moment. The dev version is `2.0.0.9001`.

Comment: In anycase, `qplot` is for "quick plots". It sacrifices flexiblity for simplicity. So it is unlikely to be possible. Those kinds of things is what `ggplot` is for.

Comment: I guess my ggplot is 1.0.1 then. Because there is always random "?" appearing on my console (prob due to some encoding problems), so I can't see some of the numbers and letters. It says ?.0.1. If someone can figure out how to get rid of those ? it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question is "is there a way to achieve this using `qplot`", I would answer - probably not, although I am not 100 percent sure.

But in anycase, qplot is for "quick plots". It sacrifices flexiblity for simplicity. So it is unlikely to be possible. Those kinds of things is what `ggplot` is for, and it is very good at it. You should use that.

In your case:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,wt)) + geom_point(size=3) + geom_smooth(method="lm",size=1)
```

Yields what you want:

[image]

Comment: `qplot` will eventually be phased out and should not be used.

Comment: I think the idea of `qplot` was good, but somehow it was never as easy to use and as robust as `plot`. It just seems to get in the way now.

Comment: I think qplot is good because it is quick and nice looking. One can always add more stuff with ggplot. ggplot has very good function. But I always feel the variables to be plotted as not exactly "aesthetics". It is awkward they have to be in the aes()